# Replace string in column in MS Excel from MS Word Macro

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I am trying to replace strings in a Excel column with a sub routine in an MS Word VBA macro, but I get the following error: *"Compile error: Method or data member not found."*

I was trying to modify this MS Word Macro to replace the values in the "Done" column ("TRUE" -> "Resolved", "FALSE" -> "Open") since I find the TRUE/FALSE values too technical. I have recorded a Macro as a Sub routine in Excel to do that but I don't know how to fit it into the code because it requires interactive communication between MS Word and MS Excel. If I just add `Call RelpaceInDone` in the macro I get the following error: *"Compile error: Method or data member not found."*

```
Sub ReplaceInDone()
'
' ReplaceInDone Macro
'
Columns("G:G").Select
Selection.Replace What:="TRUE", Replacement:="Resolved", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False, FormulaVersion:=xlReplaceFormula2
Selection.Replace What:="FALSE", Replacement:="Open", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    Repl`aceFormat:=False, FormulaVersion:=xlReplaceFormula2
End Sub`
```

Any advice?

Comment: You can't just use MS excel's code in a MS word document. Firstly you need an excel application object and a workbook object to refer to.

Answer (score 0):

Step1: Get / create Excel Application.

Step2: Get / open Excel workbook.

Step3: Replace data in column G, all Excel const should be replace with integer

Let's assume the Excel file named `Data.xlsx` is stored in the same directory as the Word document.

```vb
Sub ReplaceInDone()
    ' Word VBA code
    Dim xlApp As Object, xlWK As Object
    Dim oRange As Object, sPath
    sPath = ThisDocument.Path & "\"
    On Error Resume Next
    Set xlApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
    On Error GoTo 0
    If xlApp Is Nothing Then
        Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
        Set xlWK = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(sPath & "Data.xlsx")
    Else
        On Error Resume Next
        Set xlWK = xlApp.Workbooks(sPath & "Data.xlsx")
        On Error GoTo 0
        If xlWK Is Nothing Then Set xlWK = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("Data.xlsx")
    End If
    Set oRange = xlApp.Activesheet.Range("G:G")
    oRange.Replace What:="TRUE", Replacement:="Resolved", LookAt:=2, _
        SearchOrder:=2, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False, FormulaVersion:=1
    oRange.Replace What:="FALSE", Replacement:="Open", LookAt:=2, _
        SearchOrder:=2, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False, FormulaVersion:=1
    xlWK.Save
    xlWK.Close
    xlApp.Quit
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I used snippets of your code example to insert code into the original macro (see full code here: https://paste.ee/p/Uq3UC). Works great!